# XSLT Concatenate content of consecutive nodes

Tags: xslt

I’m new to XSLT and work on this once a year only. Here a really Basic XSLT question I can’t figure out.

I need to concatenate all the same nodes into a single text output separated by a space. Any help appreciated.

Sample of XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <root>
<properties>
      <plus>Agile en conduite tout-terrain et dans la neige.</plus>
      <plus>Habitacle logeable et commandes logiques.</plus>
      <plus>Bonne visibilité.</plus>
      <minus>Retrait du constructeur du marché canadien en 2014.</minus>
      <minus>Roulement assez sec.</minus>
</properties>
</root>
```

Comment: If you are using XSLT 2 or 3, look at grouping (in your case by `group-by="node-name(.)"`) as summarized in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's dead easy in XSLT 2.0: `string-join(properties/*, ' ')`.

So I guess you're not using XSLT 2.0, or you wouldn't be asking. And if you're only working on it once a year, it's probably easier for you to put up with the limitations of 1.0 than to upgrade. The 1.0 solution looks something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="properties/*">
  <xsl:if test="position() != 1"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I would have thought that "all the same nodes into a single text output" means grouping all e.g. `plus` together and that way it sounds like a grouping problem to me.

Comment: Indeed, I want all <plus> separated by a return. Than all <minus>.

Comment: It's always a good idea to show your required output, especially if English isn't your first language. It certainly never occurred to me that that's what you meant.

Comment: I was able to get all <plus> using: <xsl:copy-of select="plus"/>

But all text in one line. I need a return separator between them. How?

Comment: Use an xsl:for-each as in my example.

Comment: My output is text only... So this did it (XSLT1.0)

<xsl:text>&lt;Plus&gt;</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="plus">
<xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>&lt;/Plus&gt;&#13;</xsl:text>

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... Since my output was text Was able to get it with.

```
<xsl:for-each select="plus">
<xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 the `xsl:value-of` element takes a `separator` attribute so you can use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="plus" separator="&#10;"/>`, for instance, if you use an XSLT 2 or later processor.